# How to detect previous element on hover in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on the demo below. How can I detect the`id` of previous element when mouse hover over `#box-5` ?

For example I want to console log the id of the each div which the mouse moved in to the `#box-5`

```js
$("#box-5").hover(function(){
   console.log("Entering From ...")
    }, function(){
    
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
#box{
  width:320px;
  height:300px;
}
.map{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  float:left;
}
#box-5{
  background:khaki;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
<div id="box-1" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-2" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-3" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-4" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-5" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-6" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-7" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-8" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-9" class="map"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep track of the last hovered element in a variable and update it every time one of these elements is hovered

```js
$("#box-5").hover(function(){
   console.log("Entering From ..." + last_box)
    }, function(){
    
});

var last_box = null;
$('.map').hover(function(){
   if($(this).attr('id') != 'box-5'){
       last_box = $(this).attr('id');
   }
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
#box{
  width:320px;
  height:300px;
}
.map{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  float:left;
}
#box-5{
  background:khaki;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
<div id="box-1" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-2" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-3" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-4" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-5" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-6" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-7" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-8" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-9" class="map"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the hovered element's id in a separate variable and every time change it in the hover event handler function.

```js
let hoveredId = 0;

$(".map").hover(function() {
    this.id !== 'box-5' ? hoveredId = this.id 
                        : console.log(`Entering from ${hoveredId}`);
}, () => {});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

#box {
  width: 320px;
  height: 300px;
}

.map {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
}

#box-5 {
  background: khaki;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
<div id="box-1" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-2" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-3" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-4" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-5" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-6" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-7" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-8" class="map"></div>
<div id="box-9" class="map"></div>
</div>
```